# Does marginalization of some of the latent variables improve convergence in EM?

Tags: expectation-maximization, marginal-distribution, fisher-information

Given a likelihood to maximize
$$
\log p(x | \theta)
$$

Imagine that, in order to apply EM, we can augment the model with one or two latent variables. In that case,  we can derive two lower bounds:

$$
\log p(x | \theta) = \log\int_{z_1}p(x , z_1 | \theta)
\geq
\int_{z_1}\log\left\lbrace
\frac{p(x, z_1 | \theta)}{p(z_1| x, \theta)}
\right\rbrace p(z_1 | x, \theta) = \mathcal{L}_1
$$

or

$$
\log p(x | \theta) = \log \int_{z_1,z_2} p(x, z_1, z_2 | \theta)
\geq
\int_{z_1,z_2}\log\left\lbrace
\frac{p(x, z_1, z_2 | \theta)}{p(z_1, z_2 | x, \theta)}
\right\rbrace p(z_1, z_2 | x, \theta) = \mathcal{L}_2
$$
or

Is there any reason why the lower bound of the first approach should be better in terms of speed of convergence or any other property?

---

I think I got a demonstration that $\mathcal{L}_1 \geq \mathcal{L_2}$. If this is true, I would only need a demonstration that this makes $\mathcal{L}_1$ faster to converge:

The first lower bound is
\begin{align}
&
\mathcal{L}_1 =\mathbb{E}_{z_1| x, \theta}[\log p(x, z_1 | \theta)]
- \mathbb{E}_{z_1| x, \theta}[\log p(z_1| x, \theta)] 
\end{align}

The second lower bound is
\begin{align}
\mathcal{L}_2 =\mathbb{E}_{z_1, z_2 | x, \theta}[\log p(x, z_1, z_2  | \theta)]
- \mathbb{E}_{z_1, z_2 | x, \theta}[\log p(z_1, z_2 | x, \theta)]
\end{align}

Now we will show that $\mathcal{L}_1(\theta) \geq \mathcal{L}_2(\theta)$:

\begin{align}
&\mathcal{L}_1  
=\mathbb{E}_{z_1 | x, \theta}[\log \mathbb{E}_{z_2, | z_1, x, \theta}\frac{p(x, z_1, z_2 | \theta)}{p(z_2 | z_1, x, \theta)}]
- \mathbb{E}_{z_1 | x, \theta}[\log p(z_1| x, \theta)]\\
\geq&
\mathbb{E}_{z_1 | x, \theta}[\mathbb{E}_{z_2 | z_1, x, \theta}[\log p(x, z_1, z_2 | \theta)]]
- \mathbb{E}_{z_1 | x, \theta}[\mathbb{E}_{z_2 | z_1, x, \theta}[\log p(z_2 | z_1, x, \theta)]
- \mathbb{E}_{z_1 | x, \theta}[\log p(z_1| x, \theta)]\\
&=
\mathbb{E}_{z_1, z_2}[\log p(x, z_1, z_2 | \theta)]
- \mathbb{E}_{z_1, z_2}[\log p(z_2 | z_1, x, \theta)]
- \mathbb{E}_{z_1 | x, \theta}[\log p(z_1| x, \theta)]\\
&=
\mathbb{E}_{z_1, z_2}[\log p(x, z_1, z_2 | \theta)]
- \mathbb{E}_{z_1, z_2}[\log p(z_1, z_2 |x, \theta)]\\
&=
\mathcal{L}_2
\end{align}

I don't see why this should make $\mathcal{L}_1$ faster to converge than  $\mathcal{L}_2$, but maybe it has been proven for some cases such as the exponential family?

Comment: Are z1 and z2 ordered in descending eigenvalue?

Comment: Not necessarily (I haven't checked for my particular case), but if in that case the statement is true then I'm interested.

Answer (score 0):

Let me clean up your question:

First, the equation given by you seems incorrect, 
$
 p(x|\theta,z_1) \neq \int_{z_1} p(x|\theta, z_1)dz_1,
$

what holds is:
$
p(x|\theta,z_1) = \int_{z_1} p(x, z_1|\theta)dz_1.
$

Second, if you want to connect $p(x|\theta, z_1)$ to $p(x|\theta) $, use the Bayes' theorem:
$
 p(x,z_1|\theta) = p(x|\theta, z_1)p(z_1|\theta)
$
then 
$
p(x|\theta) = \int_{z_1}p(x,z_1|\theta)dz_1 = \int_{z_1} p(x|\theta, z_1)p(z_1|\theta)dz_1,
$

Third, go back to the log-liklihood:
$
\log p(x|\theta) =\log \int_{z_1} p(x|\theta, z_1)p(z_1|\theta)dz_1 \geq 
\int_{z_1} p(z_1|\theta)\log p(x|\theta, z_1)dz_1, \,\,\,\,\,(1)
$

if you further augment $z_1$ with $z_2$, then you have: 
$
\log p(x|\theta) \geq 
\int_{z_1, z_2} p(z_1, z_2|\theta)\log p(x|\theta, z_1, z_2)dz_1dz_2, \,\,\,\,\,(2)
$

Finally,  you are essentially asking why (1) is better than (2) ?

Comment: Thanks, I fixed my equation. Yes, I'm asking why (1) is better than (2). I'm preparing a little example with a Gamma Poisson mixture and I'll try to post it later. $Pois(x | \theta \sum_k \lambda_k) Gamma(\lambda)$ (2) gives a $\mathbb{E}[\log Poisson] $ lower bound and (1) gives $\mathbb{E}[\log NegativeBinomial]$